# Get information from Facebook Graph

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to pull id, gender, birthday, username, friends list and some other information about the user.

Heres my code:

```
    if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id, username, gender, birthday, friends', 'GET');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

The only thing is it only works when fields=id is the only parameter. 
Is there another way i should be doing this?

Comment: Most likely the user hasn't grated you privileges to view their birthday and/or friends, so the API denies the request. Try `/me?fields=id,username` and see if it works. If it does then I believe that is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with the Facebook API today for my App and I managed to create a simple class, maybe this method will help you out.

```
public function getUserInfo($fields = null) 
{ 
    if($fields == null) 
    { 
        $fields = array('first_name','last_name','profile_update_time','current_location', 'sex', 'birthday', 'pic_square'); 
    } 

    return $this->facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($this->fbUser, $fields); 
}
```

Basically, `$this->Facebook = new Facebook($this->apiKey, $this->secretKey);` and `$this->fbUser = $this->facebook->getUser();`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Manuel for that code. I couldn't get that working. But I removed the spacing in my array of parameters and everything works except birthday. But that's probably a permission like Paul suggested.

Comment: And now I added the Access Token so everything is working as intended. Thanks everyone for your support and insight.